# Building an a two factor authentication login scenario in Reactjs/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying To build a two factor authentication scenario using NodeJS using this an example URL: `https://jira.amazone.de/`
When you access this page the website will ask you to enter a username and password and in the second step it will ask you for a `pin code` from google authenticator
my goal is to keep listening to the page and when the user enter the pin code I should read a cookie value to check if the user is signed in or no
I am having a problem to keep listening to the page while the user login
the below code is what I did so far but it will only list the cookie in the first page which is before even the user login

```
app.get("/ssologin", function (req, res) {
// var url = req.headers["url"];
// var lastChar = url.charAt(url.length - 1);
// if (lastChar == "/") {
//   url = url.slice(0, -1);
// }
res.redirect("https://jira.amazone.de")
 res.on("finish", () => {
   console.log("finshed")
   const cookies = parseCookies(req);
   console.log(cookies)
  })
 })
 function parseCookies(request) {
  const list = {};
  const cookieHeader = request.headers?.cookie;
    if (!cookieHeader) return list;
     cookieHeader.split(`;`).forEach(function (cookie) {
     let [name, ...rest] = cookie.split(`=`);
     name = name?.trim();
    if (!name) return;
     const value = rest.join(`=`).trim();
     if (!value) return;
     list[name] = decodeURIComponent(value);
   });

   return list;
 }
```

NOTE: The Front end is reactJs I tried to do the whole process through reactjs but I couldn't find a proper `npm` that is equivalent to `Webview` in react native

Comment: Why would you need a package like `Webview` for this? *my goal is to keep listening to the page* - what do you mean by *listening*?

Comment: it is just a thought maybe i don't need it 
also listening to the page means waiting for the user to enter the pin code so i can trigger a function from my side to read some response data e.g. the authentication token

Comment: So you must send a request to the backend after the user enters the pin. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that i am a third party application and i don't have access to this link `https://jira.amazone.de/`